# Are PBOs shared across OpenGL contexts?

Tags: opengl

Are PBOs or any kind of buffer objects shared across multiple contexts in OpenGL (such as textures)?

My best guess is that **NO** as the following code is not working:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, lastFrame->pbo);
glDrawPixels(lastFrame->width, lastFrame->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, NULL);
```

lastFrame->pbo is a buffer which has been created by another  GL context. PBO's size is `4*lastFrame->width*lastFrame->height`. If instead of binding a PBO I upload data from memory (with the same size), it works fine

The `glDrawPixels` command is throwing `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

EDIT: `lastFrame->pbo` is a `GLuint` and `width` and `height` are `u_int32_t`

EDIT 2: I'm using GLFW for contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenGL specification 4.6](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) in its Chapter 5 says:

> Objects that may be shared between contexts include buffer objects,
>   program and shader objects, renderbuffer objects, sampler objects,
>   sync objects, and texture objects (except for the texture objects
>   named zero).

And

> Objects which contain references to other objects include framebuffer,
>   program pipeline, query, transform feedback, and vertex array objects.
>   Such objects are called container objects and are not shared.

A Pixel Buffer Object (PBO) is a buffer object. So it **is** shared.

Your `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error may come from not setting as current the context where you use some gl-calls. Or trying to set as current the same context to two different threads at once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont think the problem is neither of them. If I put `printf("%d\n",  glfwGetCurrentContext()==window);` where window is the desired context, I get 1 all  the time. The program currently is single threaded

Comment: This answer is totally right. The error means one of two: 1)You didn't set shared context current in the thread where you invoke GL methods,or you haven't created shared context correctly.PBO is totally shareble.It is used many times in something called async texture streaming where a thread is used to upload texture data to GPU

Answer (score 0):

> The question is if a PBO object or any kind of buffer object gets shared across multiple contexts in OpenGL (such as textures).

As noted by [@Ripi2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51366936/2327517), the GL spec allows sharing of buffer and texture objects between contexts. But that does not mean that they are automatically shared. You must create *shared* GL contexts for that to work.

> I'm using glfw for contexts

Context sharing is explained in the [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context_guide.html#context_sharing).

Comment: In fact, that was the problem. A stupid mistake from me. Thank you for solving my problem